# What type of oil is used in korean side dishes?

Tags: oil, korean-cuisine

I recently tried making the Korean side dish [gamja jorim](http://www.maangchi.com/recipe/potato-side-dishes). Although the taste was spot on it was noticeably different from what is available at local Korean restaurants due to the lack of oil.

Many of the side dishes served at our local Korean restaurants have a considerable amount of oil and I would like to know what type of oil I should be using and at what point should this oil be added? Should it be add into the pan, during cooking or after cooking?

Answer (score 4):

Toasted sesame oil is usually the go-to for Korean cuisine. It is included as a seasoning in the last steps of the recipes you link.

Sesame oil is typically used for seasoning, not cooking with. Some types of sesame oil may be appropriate for stir frys and such, but I don't think I've ever used toasted sesame oil (the very strong smelling, flavored one) for that kind of use.

Comment: The recipe actually says to use sesame oil at the end.  I suspect that the OP may have used raw or even refined sesame oil which has a very different taste.  You definitely wouldn't use toasted sesame oil for cooking, it would burn long before getting sufficiently hot.